# Auto Refresh a page in Rails 3

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, refresh

How to periodically auto refresh page with paramaters in Rails 3?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Place the following HTML within the `<head>` of the applicable views. This should not be used when the page had POST parameters sent, only GET parameters. Change the `5` to the interval, in seconds, you want the page to refresh at.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```

Though this works, I'd recommend considering using AJAX to refresh only the needed content which will not only be faster but less jolting to the user and will have a lower impact on your server's load.

This is not specific to Rails and applies to any webpage. Since Rails is server-side, and the server cannot control the browser, Rails has no control over page refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

A completely different and more modern approach is to use a service such as PusherApp. It will open a socket to the Pusher server in Javascript and listen for events that should generate changes on your page.

http://pusherapp.com/docs/quickstart

Comment: You don't have to use a paid service. [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) using something like  [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) can be set up for free on your own server with a little bit of work. PusherApp uses WebSockets itself.