# Can you poll for new content using turbolinks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, partial-page-refresh

It seems like it'd be possible to use turbolinks to automatically refresh the body of the page, but I haven't been able to find anything about how to do this. Is it possible? If so, could you point me to a resource on how to do it?

I'm not looking for [how to refresh the whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100532/863846) - that seems quite heavy. I'm also not asking about [polling](http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes-revised) for changes, or using something like [Faye](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) to keep the page in sync. While any of these methods would work, I'm specifically asking if this is possible with turbolinks since I'm new to this feature and learning what it can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about it some more, and realised I could have a very simple solution:

A hidden link to the current page

```
link_to 'current page', params, id: 'refresh_page_link', style: 'display:none;'
```

A tiny bit of coffeescript to trigger a click on that link every 5 seconds.

```
reload_periodically = ->

  setTimeout (->
    $('#refresh_page_link')[0].click();
    return
  ), 5000 # 5 seconds

$(document).ready(reload_periodically)
$(document).on('page:load', reload_periodically)
```

That results in a weird flash on the page every reload. Clearly there are better ways to do this that wouldn't have the flash. I just wanted to learn more about turbolinks.

Comment: This is not good solution if you put this javascript inside the page body. When turbolinks reloads content of body, timer is not removed, but new one is added.


This results in multiple timers (one for each reload), each triggering click and new request. Requests are canceled in javascript and only last one goes through but on the server side each request is received and handled.

Comment: @Montas - that's a good point, thanks! But you're right, this is a terrible solution, and not one I'd implement in production, with or with out the multiple reloads :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking the wrong question

[Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) is meant for when you're switching between views -- it helps limit the number of requests made to the server:

> Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.
>   Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS
>   between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and
>   replaces only the body and the title in the head

---

**Polling**

What you're really looking for is "live" functionality:

> - Ajax Polling (typically with SSE's)
> - WebSockets

Rails runs on the HTTP structure, meaning you send a request, it replies. The problem is this prohibits Rails from generating a request from server side. Technology such as [ActionController::Live](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html) has been created to remedy this, but it's sketchy

I'd recommend using a service called [Pusher](http://pusher.com/)

This is [pub/sub tech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern), works by giving you an `eventListener` in your JS, basically "listening" to any updates from your server. You can then publish the updates through [Rails' Pusher gem](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem):

```
    #app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee
    pusher = new Pusher("*************", cluster: 'eu')

    channel = pusher.subscribe("private-user-#{gon.user}")
    channel.bind "multi_destroy", (data) ->
    # do your stuff here

    #app/controllers/message.rb
    def send_message
        public_key = self.user.public_key
        Pusher['private-user-' + public_key].trigger('message_sent', {
            message: "Message Sent"
        })  
    end
```

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to "poll" the turbolink to the current page. Some kind of automatic link click every X seconds to reload only the relevant section of the page (body). Since turbolinks only load the relevant section I thought it might be possible to poll the current turbolink for an update. Seems like maybe not.